# How to post an XML file or data to a URL using httpWebRequest and httpWebResponse?

Tags: asp.net

I need to post the XML data which I will get from the database, to a URL like ...  http://www.rentals.com/aspx ... using ASP.NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write a function like this:

```
    private string SendRequest(Uri UriObj, string data)
    {
        string _result;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(UriObj);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Close();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

        _result = streamRead.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        streamRead.Close();
        streamResponse.Close();
        response.Close();
        return _result;
    }
```

The string data can be XML like `"<xmla><..></..></xmla>"` on .aspx page to get the data, you need to use `Request.InputStream` and read the stream into string, XML, etc...